# Problem with authentication in Nginx through FreeIPA

Tags: ldap

I have set up a Docker on a virtual machine and launched two containers for FreeIPA server and nginx-ldap-auth-daemon. I followed the instructions provided at https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth#required-mods to configure LDAP authorization in Nginx.

After making changes to the ngixn-ldap-auth.conf file by adding the /user location, I encountered an issue. When I accessed the localhost:8081/user page, the authorization window appeared. After entering the credentials and pressing enter, the authorization window reappeared, and the expected message that should be displayed on the page did not appear.

To troubleshoot the issue, I added the /user location to the nginx.conf file and commented it out in the nginx-ldap-auth.conf file. I then restarted Nginx. However, when I accessed the localhost:8081/user page again and entered the authorization data, I received a "502 Bad Gateway" error and was redirected to the localhost:8081/login page.

Configuration:

```
cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-ldap-auth.conf
#error_log logs/error.log debug;

#events { }

#http {
    proxy_cache_path cache/  keys_zone=auth_cache:10m;

    # The back-end daemon listens on port 9000 as implemented
    # in backend-sample-app.py.
    # Change the IP address if the daemon is not running on the
    # same host as NGINX/NGINX Plus.
    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # NGINX/NGINX Plus listen on port 8081 for requests that require
    # authentication. Change the port number as appropriate.
    server {
        listen 8081;
  root /var/www/html;
        # Protected application
        location / {
            auth_request /auth-proxy;

            # redirect 401 to login form
            # Comment them out if using HTTP basic authentication.
            # or authentication popup won't show
            error_page 401 =200 /login;
    
            proxy_pass http://backend/;
        }

        location /login {
            proxy_pass http://backend/login;
            # Login service returns a redirect to the original URI
            # and sets the cookie for the ldap-auth daemon
            proxy_set_header X-Target $request_uri;
  }
  

#  location /user {
#    auth_request /auth-proxy;
#    index index.user.html;
#    proxy_pass http://backend;
#  }



        location = /auth-proxy {
            internal;

            # The ldap-auth daemon listens on port 8888, as set
            # in nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py.
            # Change the IP address if the daemon is not running on
            # the same host as NGINX/NGINX Plus.
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;

            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            proxy_pass_request_headers off;
            proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
            proxy_cache auth_cache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;

            # The following directive adds the cookie to the cache key
            proxy_cache_key "$http_authorization$cookie_nginxauth";

            # As implemented in nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py, the ldap-auth daemon
            # communicates with a LDAP server, passing in the following
            # parameters to specify which user account to authenticate. To
            # eliminate the need to modify the Python code, this file contains
            # 'proxy_set_header' directives that set the values of the
            # parameters. Set or change them as instructed in the comments.
            #
            #    Parameter      Proxy header
            #    -----------    ----------------
            #    url            X-Ldap-URL
            #    starttls       X-Ldap-Starttls
            #    basedn         X-Ldap-BaseDN
            #    binddn         X-Ldap-BindDN
            #    bindpasswd     X-Ldap-BindPass
            #    cookiename     X-CookieName
            #    realm          X-Ldap-Realm
            #    template       X-Ldap-Template

            # (Required) Set the URL and port for connecting to the LDAP server,
            # by replacing 'example.com'.
            # Do not mix ldaps-style URL and X-Ldap-Starttls as it will not work.
            proxy_set_header X-Ldap-URL      "ldap://127.0.0.2";

            # (Optional) Establish a TLS-enabled LDAP session after binding to the
            # LDAP server.
            # This is the 'proper' way to establish encrypted TLS connections, see
            # http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html
            #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Starttls "true";

            # (Required) Set the Base DN, by replacing the value enclosed in
            # double quotes.
            proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BaseDN   "CN=users,CN=compat,dc=ipa,dc=test,dc=local";

            # (Required) Set the Bind DN, by replacing the value enclosed in
            # double quotes.
            proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BindDN   "CN=admin,dc=ipa,dc=test,dc=local";
            # (Required) Set the Bind password, by replacing 'secret'.
            proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BindPass "password";

Бычковский Сергей, [05.07.2023 13:31]
# (Required) The following directives set the cookie name and pass
            # it, respectively. They are required for cookie-based
            # authentication. Comment them out if using HTTP basic
            # authentication.
            proxy_set_header X-CookieName "nginxauth";
            proxy_set_header Cookie nginxauth=$cookie_nginxauth;
      #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Template "(&(cn=%(username)s)(memberOf=cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=ipa,dc=test,dc=local))";

            # (Optional) Uncomment if using HTTP basic authentication
            #proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;

            # (Required if using Microsoft Active Directory as the LDAP server)
            # Set the LDAP template by uncommenting the following directive.
            proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Template "(sAMAccountName=%(username)s)";

            # (May be required if using Microsoft Active Directory and
            # getting "In order to perform this operation a successful bind
            # must be completed on the connection." errror)
            #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-DisableReferrals "true";

            # (Optional if using OpenLDAP as the LDAP server) Set the LDAP
            # template by uncommenting the following directive and replacing
            # '(cn=%(username)s)' which is the default set in
            # nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py.
            #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Template "(cn=%(username)s)";

            # (Optional) Set the realm name, by uncommenting the following
            # directive and replacing 'Restricted' which is the default set
            # in nginx-ldap-auth-daemon.py.
            #proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Realm    "Restricted";
        }
    }
#}
```

```
grep -v '^$\|^#' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}
http {
  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  # server_tokens off;
  # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  # server_name_in_redirect off;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##
  gzip on;
  # gzip_vary on;
  # gzip_proxied any;
  # gzip_comp_level 6;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  # gzip_http_version 1.1;
  # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
  server {
    server_name localhost;  
    root /var/www/html;
    location /user {
      auth_request /auth-proxy;
      index index.user.html;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
  }  
  
}
```

How can I solve the problem?